# Why isn't "On the bottom of the MetroCard are three arrows" written "On the bottom of the MetroCard THERE are three arrows"?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, syntax

Recently I found this sentence:

> On the bottom of the MetroCard are three arrows and little white letters that say "Insert this way/This side facing you."

This sentence is **correct**, but I do not understand **why** it is.

I thought an object of preposition can never be a subject. The object of preposition in the sentence is :

**On the bottom of the MetroCard.**

I think we should add "there" just after the object of preposition above to make the sentence correct, like this:

> On the bottom of the MetroCard **there** are three arrows and little white letters that say "Insert this way/This side facing you."

May I know some grammar rules regarding this?

Comment: Hello, Arief.an. This is a question that it would be better to ask on our sister site, ELL. I'll give you the answer here this time. Look at a simpler but similar sentence: 'In the room was a man.' This is just a rearrangement of 'A man was in the room.' Prepositional phrases may be fronted the way the first variant shows. But the subject does not change; here it's still 'A man' (or 'a man' if it's placed after 'was'). // In my example, the prepositional **phrase** is 'In/in the room'. In yours, it's 'On the bottom of the MetroCard'.

Comment: Hi sir Edwin. Thanks for the suggestion and your answer. So if the verbs are like 'is, are, was, were, etc,' then the sentence can be rearranged. On the other hand, i presume, the sentence like : 'on the bottom of the card looks neat.'  is incorrect. Thanks.

Comment: The general question 'When may a prepositional phrase be moved to the start of a sentence?' is a lot more tricky than your single example, and you might like to ask it here, with a few examples you find on the internet. _What verbs may follow the PP?_ ... I'll be back in a few days. (Y/N)
They drove to Glasgow (iffy). But **sometimes**, just to add to the complexities, a prepositional phrase may be used as a subject (although this is fairly rare): 'Underneath the wardrobe is where I found it.' / 'After ten would be the best time to come.' Informally, 'In here looks promising' is idiomatic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there no subject in a sentence like "Under the tree is a dog"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178705/is-there-no-subject-in-a-sentence-like-under-the-tree-is-a-dog)

Comment: I'm gonna use the same example in a comment above. a) *A man was in the room*; b) *A man was there*; c) *A man was there in the room* are all valid sentences. So are a1) *In the room was a man*; b1) *There was a man*; c1a) *In the room, there was a man*; c1b) *There in the room was a man*. Note that b1) can be used in two different ways.

Answer (score -1):

It is correct to say (as stated in the comments):

> [Who] is [where].   ->   The cup is here.

as well as:

> [Where] is [who].    -> Here is the cup.

and they are both correct.

---

However, it sounds better to be to say:

> On the bottom of the MetroCard **there** are three arrows

instead of:

> On the bottom of the MetroCard are three arrows.

---

Also, I prefer:

> **There** are three arrows on the bottom of the MetroCard

instead of:

> Are three arrows on the bottom of the MetroCard